# Read user input in The Go Playground

Tags: go, input

I made my first program in the Go language and I don't understand why when I use the Go platform: (https://go.dev/play/ ) the program doesn't wait for user input.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var eleLen int
    var givenNUM int
    var TF bool

    fmt.Println("Enter the length of array: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&eleLen)

    arr := make([]int, eleLen)
    for i := 0; i < eleLen; i++ {

        fmt.Scanln(&arr[i])
    }
    fmt.Println("Enter number: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&givenNUM)

    for i := 0; i < eleLen; i++ {
        if arr[i] >= givenNUM {
            continue
        } else {
            TF = false
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(TF)

}
```

**The output that I get is:**

```
Enter the length of array: 
Enter number: 
false

Program exited.
```

I don't have the option to input the array and numbers.

Comment: The playground doesn't support interactive input. [Install Go](https://go.dev/doc/install) on your machine and run the program there.

Answer (score 1):

The notes under the Playground editor at [https://go.dev/play/](https://go.dev/play/p/v5H73QW7kiK?v=gotip) state:

> The only communication a playground program has to the outside world is by writing to standard output and standard error.